# Airflow Scheduler gives error KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found

Tags: scheduler, airflow, uid

while running docker container after the build of a local image for airflow using specific userid, then scheduler complaints above subject error.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/getpass.py", line 170, in getuser
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000'
```

can anyone suggest me best way overcome this error?

Comment: How are you running it using specific user id?

Comment: docker run -u <xxxx> imagename

Answer (score 2):

I did this dirty hack in my docker file and it helped:

```
RUN echo USER_NAME:x:UID:GID:USER_NAME:/home/users/USER_NAME:/bin/bash >> /etc/passwd
```

**USER_NAME**, **UID**, **GID** to be replaced by your own